# Where to find AlertDialog xml file

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I want to customize the android AlertDialog , I need the default xml layout file that is in android.

Where I can find it ?

Answer (score 1):

Your default XML layout file is found in the layout folder of the res directory.